# login to a https URL using HttpClient java

Tags: apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to login to an HTTPS URL using HttpClient but failed. Can I get help with my problem? this is the code that I wrote. this code is able to get the cookies part but it's not getting logged in. After logging in I need to get some data from the logged-in page.

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.example.com");
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
         HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    System.out.println("Initial set of cookies:");
         List<Cookie> cookies = httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
         if (cookies.isEmpty()) {
             System.out.println("None");
         } else {
             for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
                 System.out.println("- " + cookies.get(i).toString());
             }
         }
         
         HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("https://www.example.com/jsp/login.jsp");

         List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
         nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "xxx"));
         nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "xxx"));

         httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, Consts.UTF_8));

         response = httpclient.execute(httpost);
         entity = response.getEntity();

         System.out.println("Login form get: " + response.getStatusLine());
         EntityUtils.consume(entity);

         System.out.println("Post logon cookies:");
         cookies = httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
         if (cookies.isEmpty()) {
             System.out.println("None");
         } else {
             for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
                 System.out.println("- " + cookies.get(i).toString());
             }
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing the login button and a few more name value pairs. I'm not sure what your button is called or the value that gets sent with it.

```
List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
         nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "xxx"));
         nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "xxx"));
         nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("button", "Login"));
```

I would download [TamperData](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data/) and then go to your webpage and log in while TamperData is up. Use it to view the POST where you log in. There might be a name value pairs that's being sent that you're missing.